# Decode JSON file starting with "[" in SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoding

I have this structure. I know that this structure is incorrect.

```
import Foundation

struct Country: Codable {
    var name: String
    var capital: String
}
```

I have JSON file https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/eesti?fields=name;capital
JSON file started with "[", so I just don't understand how to encode this.
It's my first attempt  to encode this JSON file.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let urlString = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/eesti?fields=name;capital"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {

                    let countries = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: data!)
                    print(countries[0].capital)
                    print(countries[0].name)
                } catch {
                    print("Error in json parsing")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are receiving a json array so you need to decode it as array not an object

```
  let countries = try decoder.decode(Array<Country>.self, from: data!)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, could you please share any additional sources about JSON decoding, if possible?

Comment: check this article maybe it helps https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/json-parsing-decoding/